# XY coordinates of WPF button move on runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-positioning

I got a pretty weird behavior of my WPF application: the XY position of my button on runtime seems to be divergent to that when I set it in my xaml-Editor of Visual Studio (is there a name for it btw?)

It has no alignments set or panels around it, i have only set it by margins. My button has the following code:

`<Button Content="OK" Height="23" Margin="213,319,4,7" Name="button3" Width="75" IsCancel="True" Click="button3_Click" IsEnabled="False" />`

**Edit:**

The margins are fixed because it is a non-resizable dialog. As you can see, the button's slightly moved to the left and up:

xaml-Editor:

[image]

Runtime:

[image]

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: divergent  how?  And what are the surrounding tags?  Positioning with margin should be avoided amap anyway.

Comment: same question here, what do you want to say with divergent... does the button move when you do nothing or when you resize the window ...etc ... @HenkHolterman, why not positioning with the margin? what would be the alternative? (or do you wanted to say the sizing should not be done by margin? then I totally agree with you :)) ... btw, the above code has margin *and* sizes set, so one of these settings is bound to be disregarded anyway, especially when the window will be resized ...

Comment: Post the (full) XAML. This is about the surrounding Grid too.

Comment: @ArnoSaxena - Using the Margin is what the Designer does but it's awful. And never necessary. The layout in the pictures could/should be done with a simple Grid.

Comment: Having said that, there is no clear reason why the runtime should look different.

Comment: Could you please share us full XAML?

Comment: I think you have a problem understanding WPF containers. I think you should better use `VerticalAlignments` and `HorizontalAlignments` instead of that margin. Could you please paste all the XAML with Button, conatainer, list...? It would be easier to help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below link about the Alignment, Margins, and Padding Overview will help you to understand how it is works?

Else place a panel wrappers such as Stackpanel, Wrappand or Grid. It's suitable to work the layout of the controls

EDIT : The problem was with the ResizeMode="NoResize". If you remve this attribute in Window tag, then alignment would be good

[Link to Refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)

Comment: i think i have understood the concept about the alignments, margins and paddings. I just wonder, why my element even moves, eventhough my window did not resize at any time. tell me, why it should change it's XY position then?

Comment: I couldn't see your images. can you correct that one ? then i'll assist you

Comment: see it now? http://www.abload.de/img/12_03_2013_1byuwk.png / http://www.abload.de/img/12_03_2013_2xbu1x.png

Comment: In my connection it was blocked. i doubted about the horizontanalignment property. can u set to left and check once ?

Comment: setted `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`, didn't solve the problem (http://www.abload.de/img/12_03_2013_3zrus7.png)..

Comment: Sorry i couldn't see your snaps. try to update once again in SO

Comment: No hope. this kind of website still blocked in my connection.

Comment: lol! so tell me an imagehoster which is not blocked for you then?

Comment: replied you back. just check

Comment: Please, post full XAML for this screen, and we can try to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Man, that's the worst way to set the position of a UI element in WPF!

Refactor your XAML to something like this:

```
  <Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Name="TableList" Margin="5"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="button3" Content="OK"
            Margin="5"
            Width="75"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
  </Grid>
```

You see? There is a `Grid` that handles the position of all its children (in this case, a `ListView` and a `Button`).

The `Button` is put on the second `Row`, aligned to the right (`HorizontalAlignment` property).

Both the `Grid` and its children have `Margin=5`. This guarantees that the margin of every children is equal respect to the adiacent children and to other controls outside the `Grid`.

Also, the `ListView` and the `Button` are perfectly aligned.

The problem with your approach is that you set the `Button` `Width` *and* its `Left Margin` *and* its `Right Margin`. Maybe the total is not correct because the border of the `Window` eats some pixel, or simply WPF can't handle all the informations together and misses the calculation, who knows, but the consequence is that **you must leave at least one parameter free**. In my example, I left free the `Margins` from the Window. The `Margin=5` sets only the relative `Margin` respect to the other controls, but how much the `Button` is distant from the left border of the `Window` is something I leave to the WPF graphical engine to calculate.